# Colocar na função o Required

Tags: javascript, html

Quero que a caixa de texto seja obrigatória de forma a ter de a preencher, conseguem ajudar?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Please input a number between 1 and 10:</p>

        <input id="numb">

        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit </button>

        <p id="demo"></p>

        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var x, text;

                // Get the value of the input field with id="numb"
                x = document.getElementById("numb").value;

                // If x is Not a Number or less than one or greater than 10
                if (isNaN(x) || x < 1 || x > 10)  {
                    text = "Input not valid";
                } else {
                    text = "Input OK";
                }

                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

No seu `<script>` você pode tentar o seguinte código além da mensagem que você retorna:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x, text;

        // Get the value of the input field with id="numb"
        x = document.getElementById("numb").value;

        // If x is Not a Number or less than one or greater than 10
        if (isNaN(x) || x < 1 || x > 10)  {
            text = "Input not valid";
        } else {
            text = "Input OK";
            document.getElementById("id-do-seu-formulario").submit();
        }

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
    }
</script>
```

Com isso, caso o Input esteja OK, ele engatilha o submit do seu formulário.

Comment: Agradeço a sua ajuda! Um muito obrigado!

Comment: Se esta respota te ajudou, você poderia marca-la como correta! Caso contrátio, se não tiver conseguido, podemos continuar tentando te ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, tudo bem?
Não sei se entendi muito bem sua pergunta, mas vamos lá.
Obs.: tomei a liberdade de fazer algumas alterações no código.

```html
<html>

<head>
 <script>
 function myFunction() {
  var elements = {
   input: document.getElementById('numb'),
   label: document.getElementById('result'),
   
  };
  
  var rgx = new RegExp(/^\d+$/);
  
  if (!!elements.input.value)  {
   elements.label.innerHTML = rgx.test(elements.input.value)? 'Input OK' : 'Input not valid';
   return;
  }
  
  elements.label.innerHTML = 'Input not valid';
 }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
        <p>Please input a number between 1 and 10:</p>

        <input id="numb">

        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit </button>

        <p id="result"></p>
    </body>
 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando o próprio HTML dá para validar seu formulário cara basta colocar REQUIRED no seu campo input, segue um link bom para você entender e facilitar sua vida, economizando tempo ao invés de criar scripts http://wbruno.com.br/html/validando-formularios-apenas-com-html5/

Answer (score 0):

Assim fica bem mais fácil, deve te ajudar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
    <p>Please input a number between 1 and 10:</p>

        <input id="numb" type="number" max="10" min="1" required name="teste">

        <button type="submit">Submit </button>

    </form>
</body>
```

Observe que eu coloquei a propriedade `max` e `min` no `input`, isso já valida pra você o intervalo dos números que você quer que seja permitido dentro do input.

Comment: Funcionou desta forma também! Desconhecia essa propriedade, muito obrigado!

Comment: De nada @RicreedM. Depois acesse esse link: [O que eu devo fazer se alguém responder minha pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) e dê uma lida